Why does setInterval in my typewriter effect skip the second character (index 1) and display remaining characters correctly?
I am implementing a typewriter effect in my React app where I fetch a string from a URL and display it one character at a time. I expect the effect to start from the first character (index 0) and proceed through all the characters sequentially. However, the second character (index 1) is skipped, and the rest of the characters are displayed correctly.
Current behaviour:

Expected behaviour:
Additional Information:
The text state is updated correctly after fetching the data.
I've added a 500ms delay between the display of each character.
Any suggestions on improving the logic or debugging this issue would be appreciated!
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState(""); // To hold the fetched text
  const [displayText, setDisplayText] = useState(""); // For the typewriter effect
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true); // Loading state

  // Fetching text from the URL
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchText = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch("https://example-url.com/text"); // Fetch from URL
        const data = await response.text();
        setText(data); // Save the text in the state
        setLoading(false); // Loading done
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching the text:", error);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchText();
  }, []);

  // Typewriter effect logic

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!loading && text) {
      let index = 0;
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setDisplayText((prevText) => prevText + text[index]);
        index++;
        if (index === text.length) {
          clearInterval(interval); // Stop when all characters are shown
        }
      }, 500); // 500ms delay between characters

      return () => clearInterval(interval); // Cleanup
    }
  }, [text, loading]);

  // Rendering the text with a typewriter effect
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {loading ? (
        <p>Loading...</p> // Loading text
      ) : (
        <ul>
          {displayText.split("").map((char, index) => (
            <li key={index}>{char}</li> // Render each character in a list
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

I used setInterval in useEffect to append characters one by one from the fetched string. I expected the typewriter effect to start from the first character (index 0), but it skips the second one and displays rest correctly.

See Creating a typewriter effect in React (using JS). Your state updater function should be pure, since you're relying on external variables (such as index), your function will return different results when called based on the value of the external index variable, so it's not pure.

Hi, Thank you for the post. Can you please post here the exact string the query returns from the API ? Also, Is it possible for you to test it using  a simple hard coded text some like this "abc" instead of the API, please share the results in that case.

Issue
The issue here is that the effect/interval callback is mutating the index before the state update is processed. React state updates are enqueued and then processed when the function scope and callstack are completed.
let index = 0;

const interval = setInterval(() => {
  setDisplayText((prevText) => prevText + text[index]); // <--called later
  index++; // <-- mutated now!

  if (index === text.length) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 500);

index is mutated to 1 before the first state update is processed to use the text[0] value.
Solution
I suggest storing the index in state and incrementing that instead of copying parts of the text state into the displayText state. You can compute the derived "display text" value from the text and index states.
Example Implementation:
export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const timerRef = useRef();

  // Fetching text from the URL
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchText = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch("https://example-url.com/text"); // Fetch from URL
        const data = await response.text();
        const data = "uncloak";
        setText(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching the text:", error);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchText();
  }, []);

  // Typewriter effect logic
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!timerRef.current && text) {
      timerRef.current = setInterval(() => {
        setIndex((i) => i + 1);
      }, 500); // 500ms delay between characters

      // Cleanup
      return () => {
        clearInterval(timerRef.current);
        timerRef.current = null;
      };
    }
  }, [text]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (timerRef.current && index === text.length) {
      clearInterval(timerRef.current);
      timerRef.current = null;
    }
  }, [index, text]);

  // Rendering the text with a typewriter effect
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {loading ? (
        <p>Loading...</p> // Loading text
      ) : (
        <ul>
          {text
            .split("")
            .slice(0, index)
            .map((char, index) => (
              <li key={index}>{char}</li> // Render each character in a list
            ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

Demo:


function App() {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState(""); // To hold the fetched text
  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true); // Loading state

  const timerRef = React.useRef();

  // Fetching text from the URL
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchText = async () => {
      try {
        await new Promise((resolve) => {
          setTimeout(resolve, 4000);
        });
        const data = "uncloak";
        setText(data); // Save the text in the state
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching the text:", error);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false); // Loading done
      }
    };

    fetchText();
  }, []);

  // Typewriter effect logic
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!timerRef.current && text) {
      timerRef.current = setInterval(() => {
        setIndex((i) => i + 1);
      }, 500); // 500ms delay between characters

      // Cleanup
      return () => {
        clearInterval(timerRef.current);
        timerRef.current = null;
      };
    }
  }, [text]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (timerRef.current && index === text.length) {
      clearInterval(timerRef.current);
      timerRef.current = null;
    }
  }, [index, text]);

  // Rendering the text with a typewriter effect
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {loading ? (
        <p>Loading...</p> // Loading text
      ) : (
        <ul>
          {text
            .split("")
            .slice(0, index)
            .map((char, index) => (
              <li key={index}>{char}</li> // Render each character in a list
            ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />




The issue you called out is certainly that, an issue. Not sure how the OP is missing the second letter though as opposed to the first (which this issue causes)

There's more than one way to solve this, and this method works well. I do not however see a reason to create a ref to track the interval id and spread the logic between 2 useEffects. That was cleaner handled bottled up in one useEffect.

@AlienWithPizza Yeah, that part stumped me as well, but other than that I feel this is the issue OP has and every other part was reproducible with their code copy/pasted into a running sandbox.

@AlienWithPizza Effect (1) to fetch/load state, effect (2) to initiate the timer, effect (3) to handle the ending condition. (3) is separate from (2) because of the index dependency, otherwise the effect (2) cleanup function would run more often than desired. I'm sure there is room to optimize though, and I'm open to suggestions.

ah so it would, maybe a potential benefit of other solutions. Unrelated, you left the no longer needed index variable in second useEffect.

@AlienWithPizza Ah, and so I did. The joys of writing code in what amounts to a plain text editor instead of an IDE. Thanks.

I have revised your code to use a timeout instead of an interval, and I track the index with a ref.  I have revised your code so we can test by setting the string to be displayed manually
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';

export function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState(''); // To hold the fetched text
  const [displayText, setDisplayText] = useState([]); // For the typewriter effect
  const inputRef = useRef();
  const indexRef = useRef(0);

  // Fetching text from the URL

  // Typewriter effect logic

  useEffect(() => {
    if (text.length === 0 || displayText.length === text.length) return;
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setDisplayText(p => [...p, text[indexRef.current]]);
    }, 500);
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      indexRef.current += 1;
    };
  }, [text, displayText]);

  function set() {
    console.dir(inputRef.current.value);
    indexRef.current = 0;
    setText(inputRef.current.value);
    setDisplayText([])
  }

  // Rendering the text with a typewriter effect
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <input ref={inputRef} />
      <button onClick={set}>set</button>
      <ul>
        {displayText.map((char, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{char}</li> // Render each character in a list
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

I'm not 100% certain what your issue was.
